# How to check if there is no instance of an <li> with a title in a list?

Tags: jquery

**Desired Behaviour**

I want an element to show if there is no instance of an `<li>` with a title in a list.

**Current Behaviour**

The logic below is only working if there is a `title` on the first `<li>` in the list.  I think I am possibly misunderstanding how `find()` works.

**What I've Tried**

The snippet below shows the current behaviour and a test of the same logic in another scenario where all `<li>`'s *are* being referenced.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sibling_1", function() {
  // show green box if there is *not* an instance 
  // of a title in any of the li's
  if (!$(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li").attr("title")) {
    $(".woot").show();
  }
});

$(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
  $(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li").css("background", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.woot {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sibling_1">
  <p>click me - the green box should not show</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
  <p>test to select all li's</p>
</div>
<div class="sibling_2">
  <ul>
    <!-- works as intended if title is on first li -->
    <!--<li title="title_one">hi</li>-->
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li title="title_one">hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
    <li>hi</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="woot"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery [has attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/). Change `.sibling_1` click event to following.

```
$(document).on("click", ".sibling_1", function () {
    if ($(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li[title]").length == 0) {
        $(".woot").show();
    }
});
```

**Full Code Snippet**

```js
$(document).on("click", ".sibling_1", function () {
    if ($(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li[title]").length == 0) {
        $(".woot").show();
    }
});

$(document).on("click", ".test", function() {
    $(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li").css("background", "yellow");
});
```

```css
.woot {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  display: none;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sibling_1">
    <p>click me - the green box should not show</p>
</div>
<div class="test">
    <p>test to select all li's</p>
</div>
<div class="sibling_2">
    <ul>
        <!-- works as intended if title is on first li -->
        <!--<li title="title_one">hi</li>-->
        <li>hi</li>
        <li>hi</li>
        <li title="title_one">hi</li>
        <li>hi</li>
        <li>hi</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="woot"></div>
```

Comment: Your if condition is wrong I guess. It is suppose to be like this. `if ($(this).siblings(".sibling_2").find("li[title]").length == 0)`

Comment: Not wrong at all, but your's one is easier. Anyway I've updated the answer. Thanks. @JohnR